# Why is Java's Double.compare(double, double) implemented the way it is?

Tags: java, comparison, floating-point

I was looking at the implementation of [compare(double, double)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare(double,%20double)) in the Java standard library (6). It reads:

```
public static int compare(double d1, double d2) {
    if (d1 < d2)
        return -1;       // Neither val is NaN, thisVal is smaller
    if (d1 > d2)
        return 1;        // Neither val is NaN, thisVal is larger

    long thisBits = Double.doubleToLongBits(d1);
    long anotherBits = Double.doubleToLongBits(d2);

    return (thisBits == anotherBits ?  0 : // Values are equal
            (thisBits < anotherBits ? -1 : // (-0.0, 0.0) or (!NaN, NaN)
             1));                          // (0.0, -0.0) or (NaN, !NaN)
}
```

What are the merits of this implementation?

---

edit: "Merits" was a (very) bad choice of words. I wanted to know how this works.

Comment: Related to this and all the discussion here: check out this bit of JDK horribleness in the area of floating point comparison: http://publicobject.com/2009/11/floating-point-equality.html

Comment: @KevinBourrillion - The way I read it, that is actually about the horribleness of the IEE floating point standard.  Java has to behave according to the IEE standard, because that is what the hardware on a modern machine implements.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

@Shoover's answer is correct ([read it!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1726283/139985)), but there is a bit more to it than this.

As the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) for `Double::equals` states:

> "This definition allows hash tables to operate properly."

Suppose that the Java designers had decided to implement `equals(...)` and `compare(...)` with the same semantics as `==` on the wrapped `double` instances.  This would mean that `equals()` would always return `false` for a wrapped NaN.  Now consider what would happen if you tried to use a wrapped NaN in a Map or Collection.

```
List<Double> l = new ArrayList<Double>();
l.add(Double.NaN);
if (l.contains(Double.NaN)) {
    // this wont be executed.
}

Map<Object,String> m = new HashMap<Object,String>();
m.put(Double.NaN, "Hi mum");
if (m.get(Double.NaN) != null) {
    // this wont be executed.
}
```

Doesn't make a lot of sense does it!

Other anomalies would exist because `-0.0` and `+0.0` have different bit patterns but are equal according to `==`.

So the Java designers decided (rightly IMO) on the more complicated (but more intuitive) definition for these Double methods that we have today.

Comment: Thanks, Stephen. I'm marking your answer correct instead of shoover's because I wanted to know why the Java designers implemented compare the way they did (i.e. "the merits"), not just what the code did (although I didn't know that either). My apologies to shoover for not being more definite, but thanks to you both.

Comment: Due to floating point accuracy issues, I would expect nothing but problems from code using them as lookup keys.

Comment: @280228 - well yes, the keys >>could<< be generated in a way that is insensitive to rounding errors, etc.  The point is that if someone did build an application that avoided the problem of floating point errors, they would expect the Collection types to work.

Comment: @SamHarwell: Suppose a function which takes a `double` is somewhat expensive to compute; depending upon how many unique operand values are expected, such a function could use a `Map<Double,Double>` so that invocation with a value for which it has already been computed could simply return the result of that earlier computation.

Answer (score 48):

The explanation is in the comments in the code.  Java has double values for both `0.0` and `-0.0`, as well as "not a number" (`NaN`).  You can't use simple `==` operator for these values.  Take a peek into the `doubleToLongBits()` source and at [the Javadoc for the `Double.equals()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Note that in most cases, for two
>   instances of class `Double`, `d1` and `d2`,
>   the value of `d1.equals(d2)` is `true` if
>   and only if
>
> ```
> d1.doubleValue() == d2.doubleValue()
> ```
>
> also has the value `true`. However,
>   there are two exceptions:
>
> - If `d1` and `d2` both represent `Double.NaN`, then the equals method returns `true`, even
>     though `Double.NaN == Double.NaN` has the value `false`.
> - If `d1` represents `+0.0` while `d2` represents `-0.0`, or vice versa, the equal test has the value `false`, even though `+0.0 == -0.0` has the value `true`.
>
> This definition allows hash tables to operate properly.

Answer (score 2):

The merit is that it's the simplest code that fulfills the specification.

One common characteristic of rookie programmers is to overvalue reading source code and undervalue reading *specifications*.  In this case, the spec:

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Double%29

... makes the behavior and the *reason for the behavior* (consistency with equals()) perfectly clear.

Comment: Hmm, you're right, I should have read that closer, but you shouldn't assume I undervalue the specifications. I started with the Javadoc for compare(...), then moved on to doubleToLongBits(...), and then checked the Wikipedia article on IEEE 754, by which time I had forgotten all about the earlier mention of compareTo(...). So, I think you'll have to agree, overvaluing the source code isn't my problem, but inefficiently reading the specifications is!

p.s. Your link is broken.

Answer (score -1):

That implementation allows a real number to be defined as < NaN, and -0.0 as < 0.0.